# Kendo UI for angular - Grid shift click to select the rows

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to select the rows in between with a shift select. Kendo document says if we select the mode to multiple,it allows shift selection,  but its not working.

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="816" [selectable]="{enabled: true, checkboxOnly: true, mode: 'multiple' }" [kendoGridSelectBy]="'StaffId'"
            (selectedKeysChange)="onSelectedKeysChange($event)">
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken `shift` selection is not supported in `checkboxOnly` mode.